# What is the Behavior of a Singleton in ASP.NET Web Services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, singleton, mef

I want to create a logging component to log errors in my Web services layer to a database through a proprietary API. The Web services layer can be distributed across multiple application servers. I believe the logging component should be a Singleton.

My Web services layer is written in ASP.NET. My logging component is loaded dynamically through System.ComponentModel (a.k.a. MEF).

What is likely to happen when I get the instance of the Singleton? Do I get a separate logging Singleton instance on each application server?

Comment: do some reading and try to understand what a `Singleton` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817670.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will have a different instance on each server. The Singleton pattern guarantees that you will have just one instance in a given Application Domain, and each server has its own.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

In your case, you will have a single instance of the logging component per application instance running on your servers.

This is provided you have configured the component correctly via MEF.